# What are important uses of the "Net Tie" concept?

Tags: pcb-design

My understanding is that the "Net Tie" is a concept introduced by Altium and useful for Kelvin connections of a sense resistor and can not be applied in any other case.

Although it seems to be a useful feature at the first sight, it can't declare the exact connection point to the footprint, so it's not an exhaustive concept on its own, it still requires developer attention.

Example:

Given the following schematic:

[image]

We can either connect actual sense nets as follows (which is correct):

[image]

or as follows: (which is also correct):

[image]

or as follows (which is **not correct**):

[image]

by considering the same schematic using "Net Tie" concept.

However, if we would always handle a sense resistor a 4 pad component which has "Pin.1, Pin.2, Pin.sense1, Pin.sense2" independent of real pad count and placement; we can exactly declare "how" a Kelvin connection must be made.

As an example, we can define a 1206 resistor package footprint by adding `SenseX` pads as follows:

[image]

## Question

Is there any use case for which "Net Tie" is a complete solution?

Comment: I use them for mapping decoupling capacitors to power pins.

Comment: I have used net ties to tie analog and digital ground at one point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Net ties are an extremely useful concept, if used wisely. If you are part of a team where there is dedicated PCB layout resource (or you have outsourced), the use of net-ties offer additional clarity with regards to the circuit designers' intent.

They are useful for kelvin connections as you have shown (be it sense resistors or 2-wire RTD converting into a 4-wire). They are useful if you want to constrain the layout with regards to where a node might be physically taken (ie. distance constraint). Likewise their use when netnames may be merged is valuable. AGND tied to DGND at a starpoint for instance. if there is a branch in a digital clock signal where the resultant lengths are different (requiring separate signal integrity considerations)

It offers the layout and schematic engineer additional flexibility in defining what their physical intent is. It doesn't result in only one solution, it is one tool presented by the eCAD software (constraints being another).

Your example of the sense taps is a classic example and I personally would have created a separate footprint for that part to ensure the 4-wire variant had the taps exactly where I would want them - between the pads

Answer (score 2):

A Net-Tie is a solution to one specific problem, and laying out a 4 terminal resistor is not it.

Most (all?) schematic layout programs operate such that all connected points have the same net name. This is fine, until you want to name part of the net something else, for whatever reason. If you don't have a net-tie, then you end up cheating by using something like a do-not-fit zero ohm resistor, with a copper polygon across the terminals, which confuses all and sundry. A net-tie clearly indicates the intent of what you're doing.

If you're laying out a 4 terminal resistor, and you want the solution to be robust to new people unintentionally altering the schematic, then you need a 4 terminal footprint for it. Then it all just works with the system, instead of trying to cheat it.