# Current Sense Resistor Layout

Tags: resistors

For a current sense resistor, should I connect the high current terminals to the current sense terminals as shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: please provide circuit diagram and describe the design intent

Comment: It is a buck converter but I just want to know in general how the shunt resistor is connected. Are the high current terminals connected to the current sense terminals like in the figure? That's it. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449330/what-are-important-uses-of-the-net-tie-concept/449333#449333

Answer (score 1):

No, the two are already connected inside the resistor package.

If you did that, you'd see no advantage whatsoever to using a 4-terminal current sense resistor, as in effect it would be the same old 2-terminal one with all its flaws.

The sense terminals should be used for sensing only, the high current terminals for actually passing power.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what resistor you have, but if it has 4 leads then it's a kelvin connection type. 1&4 are power connections, 2&3 are sensing. You may not connect power and sense together.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the answers!